# Search through specific file types for a keyword

Tags: macos, search, command-line, find

I am using Mac OS terminal (similar to Linux) and trying to find best way to search inside all files on a computer that has extension *.py

What is the best way to achieve this?

I wanted to put 1 keyword for search and quickly show the whole path of these python files are that contain requested keyword in them..

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Mac OS should be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or, in this case, https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
grep -r -l --include \*.py keyword ~
```

- `-r` - recursive search
- `-l` - print only the file path
- `--include \*.py`- match extension

I bet there's a faster way but that's how I'd do it off the top.